# id: null when creating a new item in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

When I try to create a new Conversation item Sequelize will return an object with `id: null` eventhough there is an valid id in the database. How can I get Sequelize to return the last inserted id to the newly created item?

```js
Conversation.create({
  type: 'private',
  createdBy: 1,
}).then(conversation => {
  reply(conversation);
});
```

Will return

```js
{
  "type": "conversations",
  "id": null,
  "createdBy": 1,
  "created_at": "2016-03-18T01:47:48.000Z"
}
```

My code:

```js
const Conversation = model.define('Conversation', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  type: {
    type: Sequelize.ENUM,
    values: ['private', 'group'],
    validate: {
      isIn: ['private', 'group'],
    },
  },
  createdBy: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    field: 'created_by',
  },
}, {
  tableName: 'conversations',
  timestamps: true,
  createdAt: 'created_at',
  updatedAt: false,
  getterMethods: {
    type: () => 'conversations',
  },
});

const User = model.define('User', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'first_name',
    allowNull: false,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'last_name',
    allowNull: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  profileImg: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'profile_img',
    allowNull: false,
  },
  password: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {
  tableName: 'users',
  timestamps: true,
  createdAt: 'created_at',
  updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  getterMethods: {
    type: () => 'users',
  },
});

Conversation.belongsToMany(User, {
  foreignKey: 'conversation_id',
  otherKey: 'user_id',
  through: 'conversation_user',
  timestamps: false,
});

User.belongsToMany(Conversation, {
  as: 'conversations',
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
  otherKey: 'conversation_id',
  through: 'conversation_user',
  timestamps: false,
});
```

Comment: which version of sequelize are  you using? and type conversations? really is returning you that? 1 more thing, try adding a .catch(function(err) { console.log(err); }) in your promise code.

Comment: I'm using ```"mysql": "2.10.2", "sequelize": "3.19.3"```. The catch doesn't console.log anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was my MySQL version (5.6 instead of 5.7), updated it and now I'm getting id's of the created items in the promise.

Answer (score 28):

Yo need to put  `autoIncrement: true` in `id` field:

```
id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  }
```

Personally I would advice to skip the `id` column as `sequalize` does it automatically for you and works nicely.

hope it helps :)

Comment: When I add the ```autoIncrement: true``` or remove the id column from the model I get a ```SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error``` saying ```PRIMARY must be unique```

Comment: after making changes make sure you use sync(force:true) and restart server

Comment: I synced and restarted but it didn't make a difference

Comment: Maybe you have the counter for the autoincrement set to a value that already exists in the db. Try to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how *Sequelize* is working with `id` field, I get `null` if I do `instance.id`, bug I can get the real value at DB if I do the following:

```js
console.info(instance.id); // null
console.info(instance.get('id')); // 25 => Real ID
console.info(instance.getDataValue('id')); // 25 => Real ID
```

Something similar is happening with other fields like `createdAt` and `updatedAt`.

In order to get the real value at `id` field and other related fields, I added following logic to *Model* declaration:

```js
class FooModel extends Model {
  // ...

  /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
  public async save(options?: SaveOptions<TModelAttributes>): Promise<this> {
    await super.save(options);
    this.loadBaseData();
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
  public async reload(options?: FindOptions<TModelAttributes>): Promise<this> {
    await super.reload(options);
    this.loadBaseData();
    return this;
  }

  private loadBaseData() {
    this.id = this.getDataValue('id');
    this.createdAt = this.getDataValue('createdAt');
    this.updatedAt = this.getDataValue('updatedAt');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because if you only build without save it  then:

```
instance.id // null
```

so you need:

```
instance.save()
instance.id // someNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to FastTurtle's answer, I had `autoIncrement: true` in the Sequelize migration file, but not in the model.

The migration's autoincrement was working and the id was going up in the table but sequelize kept returning null.

Once I added `autoIncrement: true` to the model as well, it fixed this problem for me.