# Sequelize sets ID field to null (non-sequential)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with Postgres 12.4, and I prefer using UUIDs to sequential IDs, even though this always causes headaches with *any* ORM. I had previously had this working by using a beforeCreate hook that set a random UUID, but this approach becomes quite complicated if you need to do upserts, which I do, so I'm trying to get Postgres to generate the UUIDs for me. I have this working now using the following sequelize attribute definition:

```
      id: { type: Sequelize.UUID, primaryKey: true, defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('gen_random_uuid()') },
```

The problem is now that if I attempt to create a new object using `MyModel.create({name: "asdf"})`, Sequelize will attempt to upsert a row that includes the `id` field set to null. This is similar to the issue described in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074800/id-null-when-creating-a-new-item-in-sequelize), but the solution presented there is only valid for sequential numeric IDs. I've also read suggestions including setting the `omitNulls` field at the Sequelize interface level, but there are many cases where I need to overwrite values with null, so setting a global configuration like this is not a workable solution for me.

I've attempted to set this configuration at the field level, but that doesn't seem to be supported by Sequelize today. There may be a similar option by another name, but the Sequelize API reference doesn't actually seem to contain any definitive documentation for the possible fields that can be included in an attribute definition - it simply says that it can be a string or an object, with no further specification, so I can only really go by the available examples, which don't seem to show anything of the sort.

Is there any way to instruct Sequelize that my primary key field will be managed by the database and should *never* be set, without also telling Sequelize that the field is numeric and sequential?

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of a workaround, but it relies on some peculiarities of my own setup, so I'm going to leave it un-chosen to see if someone has a better alternative.

In my particular case, I'm taking advantage of the Sequelize CLI to manage database migrations, which means that each table is defined in (at least) two places - the definitive model definition loaded by my code at runtime, and one or more migrations that are used to create the table at deploy time. My solution is simply to have the two table definitions differ in a controlled way. In my migration, I use exactly the column definition listed above, and in my model class definition, I use the following:

```
    id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
```

This way, the `autoIncrement` field is not present with the table is created, and is only present to modify the library's behavior at runtime. This works, but is probably not portable to other folks' setups, and (more importantly) it may have side-effects that I'm unaware of, since I'm working outside the boundaries of the API contract.